# Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu) : Compiling on jenkins

Tags: delphi, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins, delphi-2010

I'm using Jenkins to generate automatic build every 15 minutes for a test project.

When compiling for Delphi itself does not give a problem, now when I run by jenkins it gives the following problem ...

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD
>   Studio\7.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(136,3): error : Project1.dpr(1)
>   Fatal: F1027 Unit not found: 'System.pas' or binary equivalents (.dcu)

I have already tried to run by windows command this way.

```
cd "C:\Users\carlos.santos\Desktop\teste"
call build.bat
```

And Build.bat in this way.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild "Project1.dproj" /p:config=Release /p:Warn=0
```

I have already tried to run by the Rad Studio plugin itself for Jenkins this way and it also did not work.

[image: Rad Studio for Jenkins]

I have already seen in some forums that if I have many paths or do not have the default paths of Delphi in Library path can be a problem, but I have tested this too and nothing ..

Here are the paths I have.

> $ (BDS) \ lib; $ (BDS) \ Imports; $ (BDS) \ Lib \ Indy10; $
>   (BDSCOMMONDIR) \ Dcp; $ (BDS) \ include; $ (BDS) \ RaveReports \ Lib;
>   $ (BDSCOMMONDIR) \ Bpl; $(BDS)\lib\debug; $(BDS)\bin; $(DELPHI)\Bin;

The Content of rsvars.bat are there:

```
@SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0
@SET BDSCOMMONDIR=C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0
@SET FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
@SET FrameworkVersion=v2.0.50727
@SET FrameworkSDKDir=
@SET PATH=%FrameworkDir%;%FrameworkSDKDir%;%PATH%
@SET LANGDIR=EN
```

I have third party component installed in my Delphi, but I do not know if it influences anything. Anyone who can help me will be grateful.

the difference between the properties executed by jenkins and cmd are these:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

[image: pic3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it was resolved putting the paramether `_EnvLibraryPath` with my Delphi 
 LibraryPath parameter on msbuild call, example:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
msbuild "C:\Users\carlos.santos\Desktop\teste\Project1.dproj" /p:_EnvLibraryPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib\EN;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib"
```

Answer (score 2):

There may be another cause for that same problem.
I have just experienced it and solved it.
In my case, it was related to the fact that I had another configuration besides Release and Debug, i.e. ReleaseConsumer.
My build command included specifying the configuration:

```
DoJenkinsTasks "US2D_GUI" "Config=ReleaseConsumer;Platform=Win64"
```

Now, I got that same error as mentioned above.
The cause is that it can't find the ReleaseConsumer folder with dcu files.
I solved it by creating, under c:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\lib\win64\, a new folder releaseConsumer and copying all dcu files from release to it.

Answer (score 0):

Run `msbuild` with the `/v:diagnostic` option, and you will see that none of the default environment paths are set:

```
Initial Properties:
___ResourcePath                = 
__ObjectPath                   = 
__ResourcePath                 = 
_EnvDCPOutput                  = 
_EnvLibraryPath                = 
_EnvNamespace                  = 
_EnvPackageOutput              = 
_ObjectPath                    = 
_OutputDRCFiles                = false
_ProjectFiles                  = @(DelphiCompile)
_ResolveGENTLBBindingsTarget   =
```

This is because you are missing the `%APPDATA%\CodeGear` directory on your build server (under the user that is running the builds).

Particularly, you need the `CodeGear\BDS\7.0\EnvOptions.proj` settings file, which contains all the environment variables.
Put that in place and you'll see `msbuild`'s diagnostics shows properties like this one:

```
Initial Properties:
___ResourcePath                = C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib;\Imports;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Imports;C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\7.0\Dcp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\Lib\Indy10;
```